# js external script continues execution after I switch to another tab

Tags: javascript

I am injecting an external script into my page, by doing an async call and appendChild(script) and calling onload(). The thing is, when the script is loaded, I create a chart using a constructor from the script.

The issue is, if I switch my page content (go to another tab), the script continues its execution and tells "No target element found, using `<body>` instead". So my chart loads into body and all other content is invisible because of it.

When changing tabs, I am resetting my chart object to undefined but this does not help - the script continues to execute. And I have no control over the content of the script. Is there a way on my side to handle this?

Comment: "tabs", you mean browser tabs, or some tabs widget on you web page?

Comment: widget on my web page, I am using react

Comment: So, that's the problem with the widget. It only keeps html of one (active) tab at a time. The html of other (inactive) tabs is not present when your script runs. What is the name of the tabs widget you are using?

Comment: @vothaison tabs from react-bootstrap